# Stack JTextField/JTextArea on top of ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, animated-gif, imageicon

Hello fellow programmers, quick question about a simple Java program. I am trying to create a login screen for my program. I am currently using a ImageIcon, which contains an animated gif. I want to have multiple JTextFields or JTextAreas (whichever is easier) on top of this animated gif, so that I can enter info with a really nice background. Is this possible? If so how would I start?

### *UPDATED CODE*

```
class PaintPane extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        add(enterUsername);//enterUsername is a JTextField
        add(enterPassword);//enterPassword is a JPasswordField
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend JPanel and override paintComponent() to draw the background in that JPanel. Add your JTextFields and JTextAreas (both are equally "easy") to that JPanel just like you would any other JPanel.

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Edit after updated code: You shouldn't put the code that adds the JTextField inside the paintComponent() method. That's going to add a new JTextField to your JPanel every time it's painted, which is a lot! Instead, treat the PaintPane as you would any other JPanel and add the components to it just once, whenever you add it to the JFrame. Something like:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String... args){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      //this JPanel paints its own background
      JPanel myPanel = new PaintPane();

      frame.add(myPanel);
      myPanel.add(new JTextField("text field");
      myPanel.add(new JButton("button"));

      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin. I followed what you said and it almost works perfectly. To get the TextFields to show up, I had to use repaint() and revalidate(). Now, using those resets the TextFields super fast, to the point where I cannot enter anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your updated code? It sounds like you're doing something wrong; you should just be able to add your JTextField without calling repaint() or revalidate(). (Unless your component is already visible for some reason, and even then it shouldn't be more than once)

Comment: Alright, I updated it with the code that paints the image/panel to the frame.

Comment: You shouldn't put the code that adds the JTextField inside the paintComponent() method. That's going to add a new JTextField to your JPanel every time it's painted, which is a lot! Instead, treat the PaintPane as you would any other JPanel and add the components to it just *once*, whenever you add it to the JFrame.

Comment: How would you suggest I do that? I tried adding the textFields outside the paintComponent and I get errors every time. Are you saying add the textFields inside the extended JPanel class, but outside the paintComponent? Or add it somewhere in the Main constructor, which is where I am adding PaintPane to the Frame?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I knew I was doing something wrong. Thank you so much for your help. I was doing 'add(new PaintPane());'

Comment: That might be okay if you were extending JFrame for some reason. The important thing is to not add components inside of paintComponent(), because that really screws things up. Glad you got it sorted out though.